# getting complete url in email template TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpmailer

I'm working on an app using Symfony 6 and I installed the reset-password-bundle. Everything is working perfectly except when I get the email asking to change the password. The redirection in TWIG via the "url" function doesn't redirect to the correct url. When I click on the link in the email the url sends me to localhost/mypagepath/token which gives me a 404. When I write https://localhost:8000/mypagepath/token it works and I get the changing password form. I don't understand why the url twig function doesn't include the scheme and the port . I'm running my app in dev environment with the symfony server.

Here is the line in twig. I didn't change that this is the template by default in the bundle.

```
<p>To reset your password, please visit the following link</p>

<a href="{{ url('app_reset_password', {token: resetToken.token}) }}">{{ url('app_reset_password', {token: resetToken.token}) }}</a>

<p>This link will expire in {{ resetToken.expirationMessageKey|trans(resetToken.expirationMessageData, 'ResetPasswordBundle') }}.</p>
```

I tried to change the default uri in the routing.yaml file

```
default_uri: https://localhost:8000
```

It added the https but not the port so the link still doesnt work.

I also tried to change url function to absolute_url.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the 404 page is from the Apache server and not the Symfony one. Which is kind of weird for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a specific tutorial from symfony about your topic. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/absolute-urls (min 3:20)

I really recommend to watch it because it covers exactly your case.

To make it short: How about using `{ absolute_url() }`? I know that you tried it already but it's important to understand what the difference between [`path()`, `url()` and `absolute_url()`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#functions) is.

I also recommend to revert your change to the route.yaml and try it again.

Symfony is detecting the port and the URL out of the request/response context. You can use the symfony debugging toolbar to check if all information is in the right place.

Comment: to answer concretely on my case, I changed the twig file as follow
`href="{{ absolute_url(path('app_reset_password', {token: resetToken.token})) }}"`
and I set the `default_uri:` in the routing.yaml
Now my redirection works perfectly.
Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please write `default_url` instead of `default_uri`